# How can I load config.tbz from the same USB stick that Grml is running from?

Tags: configuration, usb-drive, live-usb, grml

I've tried to put a `config.tbz` in the root of the USB stick but it's not unpacked by default and nothing useful is logged `/tmp/grml*` either (even with `log` added to the kernel command line). I've also added a `autoconfig=GRML32-FULL` to kernel line (this is the label of the stick partition) and this seems to do something as `/tmp/grml*` now has a complaint that `config.tbz` is not found (even though it is in the root of the stick).

Any ideas how to make a simple setup like this work? (The documentation for grml is a morass of options and definitions/acronyms like DCS, GCA etc., but lacks a simple example. Grml also can't do loopback/file persistence like most other distros: it wants a partition for that.)

Comment: Did you use the [tool provided by GRML](https://grml.org/grml2usb/) to create the USB?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a bit trivial: you need to pass `config` (with no other argument) on the kernel command line for the `config.tbz` to be loaded/unpacked from the root of the USB. `extract` is not needed unless you want to *narrow down* what is extracted, i.e. if you don't want the whole archive extracted. When everything works ok, you'll also see a list of the files as they are being extracted, at least if you also pass `log` (maybe even without but I didn't try that). As for how I figured this out: [the source, Luke](https://github.com/grml/grml-autoconfig/blob/master/autoconfig.functions#L1513).

Anyhow, this method isn't too useful for adding additional firmwares because the extraction happens quite late in the boot process. E.g. even though grml doesn't come with a b43 driver in its `initrd`, but loads it later from the normal root, that still happens before the config.tbz is extracted, so the (late loaded) b43 still can't find its firmwares like that. (Advice to those who think a simple `update-initramfs` would work: it doesn't because b43 fails to specify its firmware dependencies: longstanding 'bug' that's not fixed upstream because the firmwares are non-free.) Actually, it can be made to work even for this purpose, if you also use pass the `scripts` param to the kernel. That loads `/scripts/grml.sh` from the stick root by default. For something like b43 you need to put in that script `modprobe -r b43; modprobe -r ssb; modprobe b43` to reinsert it when the firmwares are in place, which they are because `scripts` luckily gets executed only after `config.tbz` is extracted. True, one could alternatively rebuild the squashfs with the firmwares added, etc.